# What would be the most efficient way to create this javascript and css heavy project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a project where users click invisible `<a>` tags on top an image of a country to make it seem that the user is clicking the country to access another page.Though the process I have created works as intended, I do not believe it is the most efficient possible method.

Here's the process:

When the `North America` button is pressed, it reveals three new buttons via this jQuery code:

```
$([nA1, nA2, nA3]).each(function(){
    $(this).css({ 'display' : 'block'});
  });
```

`nA1`,`nA2`, & `nA3` are all id's that correspond to the buttons, which by default are hidden due to the class of `.buttons` in `lister.css`:

```css
.buttons{
    display: none;
}
```

function `northAmerica` also spawns a canvas which is where the changing images appear. The canvas, and all the `<a>` tags, exist under a `div` with the id of `c`, which is referenced in `map.js` via:

```
var c = document.getElementById("c");
```

This allows for:

```
  c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/P8Eev1i.jpg')";
  c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
  c.style.display = "block";
```

to operate, which all it does is make the background of the canvas an image, in this case a picture of North America.

functions `nNorthAmerica`, `carribean`, & `cenAmerica` all operate the same as `northAmerica` does in relation to the canvas.

**Now that the fundamentals out of the way, I will demonstrate the methodology used to create a "clickable country" - the methodology that brought me to Stackoverflow:**

A single `<a>` tag is created via this html code:

```html
<a href="wiki page on the country" class="hitbox" id="id-name"></a>
```

for this example, let's use this specific `<a>` tag:

```html
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belize" class="hitbox" id="belize"></a>
```

So, in order to have `belize` to appear only when function `cenAmerica` is active and stop existing when another button is pressed, I have to do this:

```
function cenAmerica() {
  c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/DYh2sMR.jpg')";
  c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
  c.style.display = "block";
  //SHOWS
  belize.style.display = "block";
```

which therefore means I must add this line in the other two functions:

```
belize.style.display = "none";
```

And lastly actually place it on the background image of the canvas so it looks like you're pressing on the country in `squares.css`

```css
#belize{
    width:5em;
    height: 10em;
    left:210px;
    top:1px;
}
```

**And here's where's the question comes in: is there a more efficient methodology?**

What I am doing each and every single time is this:

1) Create an `<a>` tag
2)Put `idName.syle.display = "block";` in the desired function
3) put `idName.syle.display = "none";` in the other functions
4) Try to find the correct spot for the tag via css
5)Repeat

There must me a more efficient way of coding I am not seeing. This isn't mentioning the fact that the size of most countries requires multiple `<a>` tags to fill.
That's a lot of clutter code piling up real fast. 
Yet, I cannot think of another way of doing the process that is faster
I am asking for help in that regard

Apologies for the amazingly long question, but I wanted to be as clear as humanly possible. Any answer at all would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lister.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="squares.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="map.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Where do you wanna go?</h1>
    <h3>All sub-divisions are based not by cultural or political divisions, rather strictly geographical definitions.</h3>

    <table>
<!--North America-->
        <tr>
            <td><button onclick="northAmerica()">North America</button></td>
        </tr>

        <td><button id="nA1" class="buttons" onclick="nNorthAmerica()">Northern North America</button></td>
        <td><button id="nA2" class="buttons" onclick="carribean()">Carribean</button></td>
        <td><button id="nA3" class="buttons" onclick="cenAmerica()">Central America</button></td>
</table>
    <div id="c">
        <td><canvas></canvas></td>
<!--Central America hitboxes-->
        <!--Belize-->
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belize" class="hitbox" id="belize"></a>
        <!--Guatemala-->
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guatemala" class="hitbox" id="guatemalaTop"></a>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guatemala" class="hitbox" id="guatemalaTriangle"></a>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guatemala" class="hitbox" id="guatemalaMain"></a>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guatemala" class="hitbox" id="guatemalaSlip"></a>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guatemala" class="hitbox" id="guatemalaHedge"></a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
//NORTH AMERICA
function northAmerica() {

  var c = document.getElementById("c");

  let nA1 = document.getElementById("nA1");
  let nA2 = document.getElementById("nA2");
  let nA3 = document.getElementById("nA3");

//show blocks
$([nA1, nA2, nA3]).each(function(){
    $(this).css({ 'display' : 'block'});
  });

  c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/P8Eev1i.jpg')";
  c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
  c.style.display = "block";

}

function nNorthAmerica() {
  c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/1TodCjG.jpg')";
  c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
  c.style.display = "block";
  //HIDES
  belize.style.display = "none";
  belize.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaTop.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaTriangle.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaMain.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaSlip.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaHedge.style.display = "none";
}

function carribean() {
  c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/7d1VrFw.jpg')";
  c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
  c.style.display = "block";
  //HIDES
  belize.style.display = "none";
  belize.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaTop.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaTriangle.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaMain.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaSlip.style.display = "none";
  guatemalaHedge.style.display = "none";
}

function cenAmerica() {
  c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/DYh2sMR.jpg')";
  c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
  c.style.display = "block";
  //SHOWS
  belize.style.display = "block";
  guatemalaTop.style.display = "block";
  guatemalaTriangle.style.display = "block";
  guatemalaMain.style.display = "block";
  guatemalaSlip.style.display = "block";
  guatemalaHedge.style.display = "block";

}
```

lister.css

```css
button{
    width:10em;
    height:5em;
    font:sans-serif;
}
.buttons{
    display: none;
}
/* North America */
.hitbox{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#c{
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:65em;
    height:45em;
}
```

squares.css

```css
/*Central America*/
#belize{
    width:5em;
    height: 10em;
    left:210px;
    top:1px;
}
#guatemalaTop{
    width:7em;
    height:6.1em;
    left:9.5%;
    bottom:80%;
}
#guatemalaTriangle{
    width:3em;
    height:2em;
    bottom:86.5%;
    left:6%;
}
#guatemalaMain{
    width:10em;
    height:9em;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    left:3%;
    bottom: :2%;
}
#guatemalaSlip{
    height:7em;
    width:5em;
    left:12%;
    bottom:70%;
    transform: rotate(340deg);
}
#guatemalaHedge{
    width:6em;
    height: 5em;
    left:14%;
    transform: rotate(320deg);
}
```

For easier understanding, here is a small-scale demonstration of the project in a nutshell and only included the country of guatemala (under sub-division 'central america') and its `<a>` tags. I hope seeing the code in-action will make it easier to understand why I desire a more efficient methodology, specifically in `map.js`. Thank you.
https://plnkr.co/edit/D7Rzq0loF4AOyJQTnxou?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use HTML elements for this. Way too complex click areas and too much graphical stuff going on. Rectangular elements fall short for overlapped hotspots.

If you're really interested in doing this in a way that's scalable, extensible and eventually maintainable, use a JavaScript game engine. They already handle the SVG / Canvas rendering, loading and interaction events for you and provide a framework thought for these kinds of heavy UI applications. Some of them are:

- [Phaser](https://phaser.io)
- [Pixi.js](https://www.pixijs.com)
- [Crafty.js](http://craftyjs.com) (I made a full mobile VideoGame with this one)
- [Babylon.js](https://www.babylonjs.com)

...and a large etc.

Another method you might prefer if this is going in a data science / GIS direction is using data visualization frameworks. This approach might be a bit more complex and you might have to learn a bit more, but maybe it suits your interests better.

Some examples are:

- [D3](https://d3js.org)
- [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com)
- [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org)
- etc. (google "javascript vector graphics framework")

These libraries give you way more control over graphics but are a bit harder to master and might be too powerful for your application.

In general, these libraries will also take care of multi-browser rendering issues, event handling, and even mobile device support (touch events, etc.). Less time dealing with boring stuff will let you focus on making a better product.

Also, craft a JSON data structure as a database so that all of your UI gets autogenerated from a single data source. This will pave the road for building your UI using API calls.

Stop hard-coding buttons, after you hit a few hundred ids it will become an ugly monster. Instead, store SVG URLs with coordinates and metadata in your JSON (probably in a tree structure), and generate everything dynamically, either on the fly or with recursive functions.